# Table of contents (minitoc, parttoc) and line breaks

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, minitoc

I have to make a table of contents for each part of a `book` document. 
I use [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package, and `\parttoc` command.

I have line breaks (`\\`) in the chapters and sections titles in both `[]` and `{}` options, otherwise they look ugly.

In `minitoc` package, it is said that linebreaks in titles may cause the problem. The problem for my file is that LaTeX spreads the text in the title lines before `\\` until the end of the line. 
(No problems in `\tableofcontents` though, but I need a table of contents for each part separately).

How can I fix it?

In the package description, they suggest to use `\protect\linebreak`, but where should I place it? I tried several variants, none has worked.

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}

\parttoc

\chapter[Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1\\Chapter1 Chapter1]{Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1\\Chapter1 Chapter1}

\section{Section1}

\chapter[Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2\\Chapter2 Chapter2]{Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2\\Chapter2 Chapter2}

\section{Section2}

\chapter[Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3\\Chapter3 Chapter3]{Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3\\Chapter3 Chapter3}

\section{Section3}

\subsection{Subsections3}

\part{Second Part}

\end{document}
```

Please see page 1 and 5 of the generated document for ToC and MiniToC. I need the same alignment for MiniToC as for ToC (in the names of chapters).

Comment: Even though you didn't format your "minimal working example" as a code sample, the example itself was outstanding. I wish every "first question asked at tex.sx" would include an example like this one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `\\` with `\protect\newline` (and a space) in the optional arguments of your `\chapter` commands.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}

\parttoc

\chapter[Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1\protect\newline Chapter1 Chapter1]{Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1 Chapter1\\Chapter1 Chapter1}

\section{Section1}

\chapter[Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2\protect\newline Chapter2 Chapter2]{Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2 Chapter2\\Chapter2 Chapter2}

\section{Section2}

\chapter[Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3\protect\newline Chapter3 Chapter3]{Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3 Chapter3\\Chapter3 Chapter3}

\section{Section3}

\subsection{Subsections3}

\part{Second Part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for your help!!!!